# How can I solve this pushing of an array into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a text-based rover simulator and the goal is having 2 different rovers that get commands (turnLeft, turnRight, moveForward, moveBackwards) and move in a 10x10 grid. Besides, I want to log each rover's path and here is where I'm having some trouble. I created an object travelLog with two keys, rover1 and rover2. The value of each key is an initialized array []. However, when I try to moveForward, I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'.

Each command accepts one argument (in this case, the rover's name: rover1 or rover2). Since the loggin takes place in both the moveForward and moveBackwards function, I wrote this:

```js
const rover1 = {
  direction: 'N',
  x : 0, 
  y : 0,
};

const rover2 = {
  direction: 'N',
  x : 5, 
  y : 7,
};

let travelLog = {
        rover1: [],
        rover2: [],

}


const obstacles = {
  x: [0,1,2,2,4,6,7],
  y: [6,0,2,7,4,3,8],

};


    

// TURNLEFT FUNCTION

function turnLeft(rover){
  console.log("turnLeft was called!");
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case 'N' : 
    rover.direction = 'W'; 
    break; 
    case 'W' : 
    rover.direction = 'S'; 
    break; 
    case 'S' : 
    rover.direction = 'E'; 
    break; 
    case 'E' : 
    rover.direction = 'N'; 
    break; 
  }
};

// TURN RIGHT FUNCTION 

function turnRight(rover){
  console.log("turnRight was called!");

  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N' : 
    rover.direction = 'E'; 
    break;
    case 'E' : 
    rover.direction = 'S'; 
    break; 
    case 'S' : 
    rover.direction = 'W';
    break; 
    case 'W' :
    rover.direction = 'N'; 
    break; 
  }
};

// FUNCTION TO CHECK IF THERE IS ANY OBSTACLE AHEAD.

function checkObstacle (rover,otherRover){
  for (let i = 0; i < obstacles.x.length; i++){
    if(obstacles.x[i] === rover.x && obstacles.y[i] === rover.y){
      console.log('An obstacle was found! Order aborted!');
      return true; 
    } else if(otherRover.x=== rover.x && otherRover.y === rover.y){
      console.log('Another rover found in your path! Order aborted!');
      return true; 
    } else {
      return false; 
    }
  }
};

// MOVE FORWARD FUNCTION

function moveForward (rover) {
    console.log("moveForward was called");
    travelLog[rover].push(['[x' + rover.x +',' + 'y' + rover.y + ']' ]);
    
    if(rover.direction === 'N' && rover.y > 0 ){ // NORTHBOUND MOVEMENT
        rover.y--;
        if(checkObstacle()){
          rover.y++;
        };
       

    } else if(rover.direction === 'W' && rover.x > 0){ // WESTBOUND MOVEMENT
      rover.x--;
      if(checkObstacle()){
        rover.x++;
      };
    

    } else if(rover.direction === 'S' && rover.y < 9 ){ // SOUTHBOUND MOVEMENT
      rover.y++;
      if(checkObstacle()){
        rover.y--;
      };
    
  } else if(rover.direction ==='E' && rover.x <9){ //EASTBOUND MOVEMENT
        rover.x++; 
        if(checkObstacle()){
          rover.x--;
        };
              
    } else {
      console.log('Your order tried to put the rover off the grid! Order cancelled!');
    };


    console.log(`The new position of the rover is heading ${rover.direction} row ${rover.x} column ${rover.y}`);
}
```

I expect the new position of the rover to be logged into the object travelLog, in its corresponding key (either rover1 or rover2).

Comment: You haven't shown us what calls `moveForward()`, as the parameter passed through will determine whether the property of the object can be found

Comment: If I am understanding you well, the parameter passed would be either rover1 or rover2.

Comment: Not necessarily... if you pass `moveForward(rover1)` then you are passing the object `rover` not the string.  You can't get the property of an object using an object.  If you pass `moveForward("rover1")` then it would probably work... or see seelts answer, which has a nicer solution by adding a `name` property to the object

Comment: One weird thing about your code is the moveForward function. Why don't you use switch cases? Also you check for an obstacle, if yes do the reverse action. Can't you just do the action if there is not an obstacle?

Comment: I'm passing moverForward(rover1). Sorry if I don't explain myself well and thank you for your help.

Comment: ok @ÁlvaroZájaraCamilo - then definitely look at seelts answer.  You still call `moveForward(rover1)`

Answer (score 3):

When you call `travelLog[rover]`, `rover` is not a string which can be used as a key for the object. Instead it is object itself.
So, you need to have a name of that rover like `rover.name` (which will be `rover1`) and then use it: `travelLog[rover.name]...`.

---

Example

```js
const rover1 = {
  name: 'Bob',
  direction: 'N',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
};

const rover2 = {
  name: 'Mike',
  direction: 'N',
  x: 5,
  y: 7,
};

let travelLog = {};

// ...

function moveForward(rover) {
  console.log("moveForward was called");
  if (!travelLog[rover.name]) {
    travelLog[rover.name] = [];
  }
  travelLog[rover.name].push(`Rover ${rover.name} moved to [x: ${rover.x},y ${rover.y}]`);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I see, but if I set rover.name, then the function cannot be reused with rover2, right? I was hoping that, by passing the rover.name as an argument for the function I could also include it automatically in the push method. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not? You may call the same function on any rover. The only addition you will have to make is to add a `name` field in all your rovers-objects.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer

Comment: By the way, you are `push`ing an array to array. I don't think you really need it. You can just push a string ```push(`[x: ${rover.x},y ${rover.y}]`)```

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna follow your advice. I'll let you know how it goes. @seelts, thank you so much!

Comment: I've updated the example to include rover name in the log.